# Where did prejudice against left-handed people originate from?

Tags: cultural-history

I came across this [Tweet](https://twitter.com/tweetolectology/status/1166259827775016960) recently which lists many

> different words used in traditional dialects to refer to left-handed people[.]

It looks like a majority of the English terms listed there are all quite derogatory. There certainly exists (and/or existed) some sort of prejudice against left-handed people in many different cultures, eastern and western.

Where did prejudice against left-handed people originate from?

Comment: Some prior research would have improved this question. The prejudice is [widespread and ancient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_against_left-handed_people). I doubt you'll be able to precisely trace it. See e.g. Adam and Eve -- left was already perceived as feminine and inferior then.

Comment: Just because a word seems derogatory now, it doesn't mean it was used with that intention when it was written down in an old document. For example, while "retarded" is exclusively used as an insult today, in the past it was the neutral term for a medical condition. And not to mention the names of some ethnicities which change from preferred to taboo every few decades...

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: When is "then"?

Comment: @R..: See Lars's answer. Basically as far back as the sources that the Genesis draws onto.

Comment: I was mainly confused by how it seemed to refer to "the time of Adam and Eve", which really has no historical meaning, but it looks like you meant "the time we can trace the origins of the story to".

Comment: Anti-lefty-ism would not likely predate written language. Current answer does not address this.

Comment: @axsvl77 'Anti-lefty-ism would not likely predate written language.' Not so. See [The Left Stuff](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=HY_x01AMFqAC&dq=%22left-handed%22+prejudice+non-+%22literate%22+societies&source=gbs_navlinks_s). Kushner also cites research by Robert Hertz refuting the assertion that anti-leftism was only a trait of literate societies: "among the Maori
and other aboriginal peoples. In all these societies the right hand is
associated with the holy, and the left with illegitimacy and the occult."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Although this is an enormously broad question in that we are talking about thousands of cultures across thousands of years, the prejudice against left-handers has been fairly widespread. **If the answer had to be boiled down to one or two words, those words - for a variety of reasons ranging from necessity to social pressure to belief systems to practicality - would most likely be 'conformity' and 'normality'**.

Nonetheless, there are important qualifiers and exceptions which cannot be ignored. Discrimination against minorities probably dates back to the beginning of time but minorities have also been subjected to varying degrees of discrimination at different periods of time and in different areas of life, and thus it is with left-handers. This bias, as noted by the OP, is evident in languages:

> The words left and left hand in almost all the world’s languages are
>   synonyms for “defective” or “sinister.”<sup>19</sup> The word for left in Latin
>   and Italian is sinistra, in French it is gauche, and in English left
>   comes from the word lyft for broken, while in German, linkisch is
>   associated with awkwardness.<sup>20</sup> Labeling someone as lefthanded (levja)
>   in Russian is a metaphor for deceptive or untrustworthy.<sup>21</sup> In
>   Mandarin (Chinese) the character for left, zoû, is variously
>   translated as weird, unorthodox, wrong, incorrect, different,
>   contrary, or opposite.

*Source: Howard I. Kushner, '[Other Hand: Left Hand, Right Brain, Mental Disorder, and History](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=gN02DwAAQBAJ&printsec=copyright&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)' (John Hopkins University Press, 2017)*

Note also that the percentage of left-handers in different time periods and cultures is often hard to determine. This is not only because we lack data before the modern era (note, though, this [research on cave painting](https://science.howstuffworks.com/life/inside-the-mind/human-brain/theres-a-study-that-the-stone-age-had-just-many-lefties.htm)) but also because the data we do have is muddied by a [reluctance to admit to left-handedness](https://www.mub.eps.manchester.ac.uk/science-engineering/2017/08/13/unravelling-mystery-left-handedness/) in some cultures and, until fairly recently, the forced use of the right hand. Further, people are [left- or right-handed to different degrees](http://www.rightleftrightwrong.com/measuring.html).

Professor of Science & Society [Howard I. Kushner](http://lchc.ucsd.edu/Kushner), in *[Other Hand: Left Hand, Right Brain, Mental Disorder, and History](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=gN02DwAAQBAJ&printsec=copyright&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)* (2017), while noting that there are societies which are exceptions, summarises that

> ...the history of left-handedness parallels that of disabilities. Thus,
>   left-handedness was understood as a sign of abnormality and of the
>   profane, which was opposed to the normal or the sacred.
>
> ...toleration of left-handedness serves as a barometer of wider
>   cultural toleration and permissiveness. Societies and cultures that
>   discriminate against left-handers are also less tolerant of other
>   forms of diversity.

Thus, there have been variations in the percentage of reported left-handers in cultures: the more conformist the culture, the lower the percentage of reported left-handers.

> Practices resulting in the reduction of left-handers in a population
>   have been referred to as “the cultural pressure hypothesis.”
>   Psychologist John L. Dawson found support for the hypothesis in his
>   comparison of the Temne of Sierra Leone with Arunta aboriginals of
>   Central Australia. The Temne culture, being more conformist, reported
>   a 3.4 percent left-handed rate, compared with the 10.5 percent
>   reported among the more permissive Arunta.

*Source: Kushner*

Dawson's hypothesis, where obedience and conformity are highly valued, is not the only explanation which has been forward for the regional differences, but it perhaps has more supporting evidence than the genetic one which is complex and hard to prove. The genetic theory is partly undermined by the notably [higher incidence of left-handed writers](http://www.rightleftrightwrong.com/statistics.html) among Americans under the age of 30 (15%) compared to those over 65 (6%); when the latter were children, it was still not uncommon for left-handed children to be forced to use their right hand. On the other hand, left-handed parents are more likely to have left-handed children.

Conformity, of course, has practical advantages for a society and was essential at times. For example, in the Greek [phalanx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalanx), the shield had to be held on the left arm to protect the man to one's left. A left-hander had to adapt to the majority or the phalanx would fall apart in combat. Thus, conformity was a necessity for survival. On the other hand, left-handed [gladiators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gladiator) held an advantage over right-handed opponents, but they invariably fought as individuals. Conformity, if anything, worked against these individuals when in the arena.

Religion has also played a large part in the [bias against left-handed people](https://allthatsinteresting.com/left-handedness-evil):

> Judeo-Christian religions attributed the left with femininity and
>   inferiority, as Eve appeared on and developed from Adam’s left side.

Evidence of bias against left-handers in the Old Testament can be interpreted in different ways, but it's probably fair to say that it mostly (and simply) reflects the prevalence of right-handers in society - so biased, yes, but not to the extent that became evident later. The more stridently biased views against left-handers in Europe, the Middle East and north Africa seem to stem more from the middle ages in all three of the main religions. [Among Catholics](http://www.rightleftrightwrong.com/history_recent.html),

> ...left-handedness was vigorously oppressed in medieval Europe, albeit
>   not in any systematic way. Left-handers were routinely accused of
>   consorting with the devil...

while [in Islam](https://sites.psu.edu/clarep/2017/08/12/left-handers-around-the-world/),

> Muslims must handle food and write with the right hand. Using the left
>   hand in public and greeting another person with the left hand is a
>   sign of disrespect.

Rather than lessening with time, the prejudice against left-handers became very pronounced in 18th and 19th century schooling with [children forced to write with their right hand](https://www.rightleftrightwrong.com/history_recent.html). As *TheHonRose* points out in a comment, this [persisted well into the 20th century](https://www.rightleftrightwrong.com/history_recent.html).

> Despite the limited reforms of the Age of Reason and the Age of
>   Enlightenment, the 18th and 19th Century were particularly hard on
>   left-handers, and discrimination against them became engrained and
>   institutionalized. Even in the relatively free societies of North
>   America and Western Europe, deliberate and sometimes brutal attempts
>   to suppress left-handedness and impose conformity in the education
>   system were endemic during this time, including such practices as
>   tying a child’s left hand behind his chair or corporal punishment for
>   anyone caught writing with the left hand.

Religion had much to do with this, but it was not the only factor. Left-handers need to be [taught writing differently](http://handedness.org/action/leftwrite.html), something perhaps not easily grasped by a right-handed teacher.

> Languages that are written left-to-right, like English, are more
>   difficult to write with the left hand -- a right-hander writes away
>   from his body and pulls the pencil, while a left-hander must write
>   toward his body and push the pencil.

Anti-leftism was further reinforced by the views of the Italian criminologist [Cesare Lombroso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cesare_Lombroso) (1835-1909) [who](https://www.rightleftrightwrong.com/history_recent.html)

> identified left-handedness as a mark of pathological behaviour,
>   savagery and criminality.

However, the anti-left bias has not been evident throughout all cultures, and some cultures recognized both positives and negatives to left-handedness. [For example](https://allthatsinteresting.com/left-handedness-evil),

> The ancient Celts, for instance, associated the left with femininity —
>   the source of all life — and thus worshipped the left side, treating
>   it as sacred.

Also, in China, Kushner and others have noted ambiguities concerning the superiority of the right hand. For example,

> In ancient China good fortune was attributed to the left hand. “On
>   occasions of festivity to be on the left hand is the prized position;
>   on occasions of mourning the right hand,” wrote Lao Tse, in the most
>   widely read Chinese book in the world, the Tao te Ching (ca. 6th
>   century BCE).

*Source: Kushner*

Plato argued strongly against the negative attitude towards the left hand:

> The negative attitudes toward left-handedness, while persistent, were
>   not universal. In The Republic (380 BCE) Plato rejects the popular
>   negative characterization of the inferiority of the left hand and
>   condemns the practice of restraining its use. Conceding that the right
>   and left hands have different tasks, Plato points out that, like the
>   two feet, the two hands are complementary: “In natural ability, the
>   two limbs are almost equally balanced; but we ourselves by habitually
>   using them in a wrong way have made them different.”

*Source: Kushner*

---

Other source:

*Daniel M. Abrams  and Mark J. Panaggio, '[A model balancing cooperation and competition can explain our right-handed world and the dominance of left-handed athletes](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rsif.2012.0211)' (Journal of the Royal Society of Interface, 2012)*

Comment: According to popular belief, there are more left-handed in south hemisphere. If it is true, it explains why Arunta aboriginals of Central Australia have more left-handed  compare to the Temne of Sierra Leone.

Comment: @MiFreidgeimSO-stopbeingevil According to Clare Porac PhD, Professor Emerita of Psychology, "The highest rates of left-handedness, 10%, occur in North America, Australia, New Zealand and western Europe. The lowest rates, 4 to 6%, are in Asia, Africa and South America." Kushner says likewise.

Comment: The Zohar cannot be used to describe Jewish attitudes before the 13th century

Comment: @Henry Good point. That reference needs improvement.

Comment: There ought to be some discussion about _sinister_ in here somewhere.

Comment: @shoover Kushner says quite a lot on language (including *sinister*) and I'm still working on this answer. Problem is trying to keep it to a manageable length...

Comment: "On the other hand"(!)

Comment: Prejudice against left-handedness persisted in the UK well into the 20thC. My mother, born 1920, was forced to write with her left-hand, and there is a suggestion that George VI (born 1895) at least partly owed his speech impediment  to the same cause.

Comment: @TheHonRose Indeed, likewise my father born in 1935. Seems I forgot the 20th cent in my answer!

Comment: My comment **should** obviously have said she was forced to write with her **right** hand! :-{

Comment: @TheHonRose Yes, that's what I assumed :)

Comment: That insistence that students write with their right hand was going strong in the fifties when I was in elementary school. Luckily, I was right handed.